# How to add a value to the various position of a int list?

Tags: c#

For example

- List contains integer values 34, 78, 20, 10, 17, 99, 101, 24, 50, 13
- and the value to put is 11 at position 1, 4 and 5
- Position is the index value which starts from 0
- so the final result is => 34, 11, 78, 20, 10, 11, 17, 11, 99, 101, 24, 50, 13

My current code is as follows:

```
List<int> list_iNumbers = new List<int>();
list_iNumbers.Add(34);
list_iNumbers.Add(78);
list_iNumbers.Add(20);
list_iNumbers.Add(10);
list_iNumbers.Add(17);
list_iNumbers.Add(99);
list_iNumbers.Add(101);
list_iNumbers.Add(24);
list_iNumbers.Add(50);
list_iNumbers.Add(13);

List<int> list_iPosition = new List<int>();
list_iPosition.Add(1);
list_iPosition.Add(4);
list_iPosition.Add(5);

int iValueToInsert = 11;
```

> Now How to insert at these positions and get the correct result?

Comment: -1 for _impressive_ searching effort.

Comment: Your example code is misleading against what you want. If you dont need it then get rid

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`Insert(index, element)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sey5k5z4.aspx) method instead of `Add`. Something like that:

```
foreach(var pos in list_iPosition.OrderByDescending(x => x))
    list_iNumbers.Insert(pos, iValueToInsert);
```

You have to do it from the last index, to make it right. That's why I used `OrderByDescending` first.

Answer (score 1):

Non Linq Solution:

```
For(int i = 0; i<count_of_numbers_to_insert; i++)
{
    list_iNumbers.Insert(pos+i, valueToInsert);
}
```